# Throwing exception in @Before, catching in @AfterThrowing

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, aspect

I created a @Before Advice that throws an exception and tried to catch it in another @AfterThrowing, but it does not work.

If the exception is not thrown in the advice, but directly in the method, it works.

If it is thrown in the advice, the @AfterThrowing is not executed.

Why does it behave like that?

Comment: As far as i know, catching exceptions only works in `@Around` advice. `@AfterThrowing` is executed after the exception is thrown (as the name implies), so you can't catch the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `@AfterThrowing` means: catch the event that an exception is thrown from *within* the captured method. But `@Before` means: do something *before* (i.e. outside) the captured method. So your control flow never reaches a point where it could satisfy the condition for the `@AfterThrowing` advice.

So either you do what Frank told you (use an `@Around` advice) or, if you have control over the caller as well as the callee part of the code, you could do this (quite ugly):

- `@Before("execution(myMethod)")` (possibly throwing an exception)
- `AfterThrowing("call(myMethod)")`

I have not tested it, but it should work because of this control flow:

```
[before call]
call(myMethod)
  [before execution]
  execution(myMethod)
  [after execution]
[after call]
```

I.e. "before execution" is already "within call".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the 2 advices are in same aspect? If not, have you declared a precedence to define the weaving order?

Anyway, if you want to do something before a method, and something after depending on what you did before, you should be using an `@Around` advice instead. You might not even need an exception (which is costly) to control the flow that way.